# Log4j2 File location not picked up in Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, log4j2, weblogic12c

I am deploying an EAR application on Weblogic 12c. I am looking to configure log4j2 and putting the following in web.xml (of the web project) is not working (file is not picked up by the application).

```
<context-param>
<param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
<param-value>file:///webapps/apps/appName/log4j2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I get the error

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

If i mention the path to the log4j2.xml file in the weblogic startup script (`-Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml` ), it picks up the log4j file. How can I get the `<context-param>` setting to work? I am running weblogic from within Eclipse (STS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to double-check: have you added the log4j-web dependency to the classpath? Without that the context parameter won't work.

Also, be aware that the specified `file:` path will be resolved relative to the web context root. Essentially it will return the result of [ServletContext.getResource(path).](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource(java.lang.String))

You may be able to see what is going wrong if you set system property `-Dorg.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level=TRACE`. That will print internal Log4j2 logging to the console.

Comment: I do have the the log4j-web dependency. I have changed my config to use the -Dlog4j.configurationFile parameter. I did not understand the part where you said the "file" path will be resolved relative to context root. I have other projects (on tomcat) where i can mention any location on the drive and it picks up my log4j file.

Comment: I meant the value of the contex-value configured in web.xml: you mentioned `<param-value>file:///webapps/apps/appName/log4j2.xml</param-value>`. That path is interpreted as relative to the web app root.

Comment: This is good information. I did not know it was relative to the context root. Probably that is why my config was not getting picked up. I'll accept your answer as it explains why my config file was not getting picked up.